# swift image for button is too big

Tags: ios, swift, image, button, size

I am setting images for buttons like this:

```
let itemImageURL = "\(self.view.getServerPath())image?path=\(league.logo!)"
let url = NSURL(string: itemImageURL )
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
button.setImage(UIImage(data: data!), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

They appear before the button text and it is exactly what I want.
But how can I make the images smaller?

Comment: you can set content edge inset of button for both title and image.you can set that to make image/title smaller.

Comment: I tried and it does not seem to influence the size of the image. I must mention that my button is as wide as the screen and has the title and image centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the scale parameter for uiimage:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(data: data!, scale: 3), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Resize the image to the button size, and add it as background image

```
func resizeImageWithAspect(image: UIImage,size: CGSize)->UIImage
{
    let oldWidth = image.size.width;
    let oldHeight = image.size.height;

    let scaleFactor = (oldWidth > oldHeight) ? size.width / oldWidth : size.height / oldHeight;

    let newHeight = oldHeight * scaleFactor;
    let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;
    let newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);

    if UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(#selector(NSDecimalNumberBehaviors.scale)){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize,false,UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);
    }
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    }

    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, size.height));
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

use:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(resizeImageWithAspect(UIImage(data: data!)!,size:button.bounds.size), forState: .Normal);
button.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
button.clipsToBounds = true;
```

**Warning**
at your code you wrote

```
let url = NSURL(string: itemImageURL )
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
```

Doing this in `main thread` is a really bad idea! take a look at the next code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://abrahampacana.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/quabbin-11.jpg")
print(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) //1463505118
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
print(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) //1463505138
```

this loading took 

## 20 seconds

this is 20 seconds that the app is stuck and user is waiting when nothing happens and nothing is responding.
you should at least use background thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)) {
    //this is background thread
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://abrahampacana.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/quabbin-11.jpg")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

    //now return to main thread to update the view
    //UI should always update from main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        button.setImage(...)
    }
}
```

another solution: using [NSURLSession](https://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession)

Comment: great advice regard using dispatch_async. Thank you!